# Reconfiguring the music lens for Audacious

Tags: unity, banshee, music, lenses, audacious

As much as I love Banshee for managing my library, its a bit slow (on my laptop) to use as a media player when I just fancy listening to a song and it also lacks the plugins for enhancing the sound which Audacious has. I was wondering if the music lens could be modified to still scan Banshee's library but to open the selected music in Audacious instead?

Answer (score 2):

Select your default application as audacious.
The music lens by default searches banshee music database and opens files using default music player.

To change default application, search for system info in dash, go to default applications tab and select your desired application. An alternate way of doing this would be to right click the file, select properties, select 'Open with' tab, and choose default application.

Comment: I have tried this before and it doesn't work. 11.10 always opens with Banshee and 12.04 always opens with Rhythmbox :(

Comment: did you try the right click- select open with thing??

Comment: Yes - I've also been into defaults.list and find+replaced every Rhythmbox entry with Audacious :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are an **Ubuntu 12.10** user, there is a music lens scope available for **Audacious**. To install it, enter the following commands into a Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:markjtully/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-audacious
```

Then, log out and log back in again.